# htaccess url redirect with subdomain and path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've got two subdomains connected to two domains and a path and I need to redirect to a a new domain with the same subdomain without the path i.e.

```
www.subdomainone.olddomain.com/path/article -> www.subdomainone.newdomain.com/article
www.subdomainone.olddomaintwo.com/path/article -> www.subdomainone.newdomain.com/article

www.subdomaintwo.olddomain.com/path/article -> www.subdomainone.newdomain.com/article
www.subdomaintwo.olddomaintwo.com/path/article -> www.subdomaintwo.newdomain.com/article
```

I am not familiar with htaccess rules and I have tried using the testers online but cannot solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this generic rule on `olddomain`'s site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:fr(?:-ca)?/)?(.*)$ http://www.%1.newdomain.com/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: I don't want the 'path' part of the path though i.e. just the article

Comment: also path can have a hyphen aka path-pathy/article

Comment: this works but I have another follow up. the path can either be /fr or /fr-ca or /en-ca. Is there a way to just look for /fr and /fr-ca ? Thanks @anubhava you've been a tremendous help

Comment: also the /fr and /fr-ca and /en-ca path can be open instead of multiple i.e. olddomain.com/fr instead of always olddomain.com/fr/article/title-of-article

Comment: thanks in advance @anubhava you have really helped and taught me a lot

Comment: thanks I figured out the last part. Your help is much appreciated, though.

Answer (score 0):

Apache has `url rewrites` set of simple regex that let you do any king of such operation, all incomming traffic URL wil be rebuild before pointing to the right path (if is that what are you looking for).

Write storng rules that do not rebuild old URLs that stay the same.

A mor trustes solution (as you migrated to new urls) is to rewrite all old URLs but not prompt users to the page but rather sending to the user a redirect HTTP to the new url so you avoid the physical user using them and they will be forgotten in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

```
example request:     
http://subdomain.olddomain.com/path/article/pme

htaccess 

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(?:path(?:-pathy)?/)?(.*)$ http://%1.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

This accounts for a hyphen in the path also for a dynamic subdomain.

new url: http://subdomain.newdomain.com/article/pme
```